# Mismatch of memory location

Tags: atmega

I am getting this error when I burn with [eXtreme Burner](https://extreme-burner-avr.software.informer.com/download/).  The LED turns on but does not blink. I am using ATmega8 AVR board.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"mismatch at location 0x0000" often happens when the ISP clock frequency is too high. Try reducing the clock in your programmer.

Answer copied from here:
https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/solvedatmega-8-mismatch-location-0x0000